# Syntax to search on modified date and creation date column of document library using FullTextSqlQuery

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery

In sharepoint 2007 please let me know how to perform FullTextSqlQuery on document library date column

Answer (score 0):

you should try as follow:

```
SELECT LastModifiedTime FROM Scope() etc
```